# Odd behaviour when dashes are add in a table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

Using the following MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.81cm,tmargin=2.54cm,rmargin=2.54cm,bmargin=2.52cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Power levels of Background loads}
    \parskip-5pt
        \centering
    \begin{tabular}{llS[table-format=4.0]}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Loads}} & \textbf{Power Consumption} (\si{kWh})\\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Background} & Fans (Slide) & 350\--- 600\--- 750 \\ 
    & Dehumidifier (Therm)  & 500\--- 620\--- 785  \\ 
    & Refrigerator (Therm) & 480\--- 580\--- 725 \\ 
    & Heater (Therm) & 750\--- 1000\--- 1500 \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular} 
    \label{powertable2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I get the following table :

[image]

But when I remove the dashes I get :

[image]

As you can see in the second pic, the numbers are centered. I want the numbers to remain centered even when I use the dashes `\---`. Why do they indent to the right when dashes are added ?

Comment: why don't you use `--` instead of `\---`?

Comment: The `S` column is meant for one number, not many. Just use three `S`. By the way, `\---` is not the same as `---` (an em-dash), in fact `\---` is an optional hyphen (`\-`) and an en-dash `--`.

Comment: @MarioS.E. I get a siuntix error if I do that

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel But I don't want to split into 3 columns (is that was adding extra S's do ? ) I tried that and the table blew out of proportions.

Comment: @Razor Well, either that, or manual adjusting. `S` does not work that way.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel How can I manually adjust it ? Surely there is an efficient way to do this. I can't believe it's really hard to add 3 numbers next to each other separated by a dash ?!

Comment: @Razor `\-` denotes a discretionary hyphen, so `\---` is just an invisible character followed by `--` which is the way an en-dash is input.

Comment: @egreg oh .. Didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `S` column does only parse one number, you will need to use three `S` columns with the dash between them, e.g.

```
\begin{tabular}{llS@{--}S@{--}S}
```

but the problem is the wide column heading `Power Consumption (kWh)` which (even combined with `\multicolumn`) doesn't work well with three very small columns.

For such simple values, this might be easier.

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.81cm,tmargin=2.54cm,rmargin=2.54cm,bmargin=2.52cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand*{\0}{\hphantom{0}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Power levels of Background loads}
%    \parskip-5pt
        \centering
    \begin{tabular}{llc}
        \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Loads}}     & \textbf{Power Consumption} (\si{kWh}) \\ \midrule
        \textbf{Background} & Fans (Slide)         &           350--\0600--\0750           \\
                            & Dehumidifier (Therm) &           500--\0620--\0785           \\
                            & Refrigerator (Therm) &           480--\0580--\0725           \\
                            & Heater (Therm)       &            750--1000--1500            \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular} 
    \label{powertable2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't expect it to be this difficult (compared to MS Word that is). I would have never guessed how to do this :S